# Query from table and also get value from another table column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two tables that looks something like this (made as example):

Table **sales**:

```
| ID |           date           | displayname | status |
| 1  |   2020/08/03 16:25:26    |     Angel   |   OK   |
| 2  |   2020/08/03 16:25:26    |     Angel   |   OK   |
| 3  |   2020/08/03 16:25:26    |     Cabil   |    X   |
| 4  |   2020/08/03 16:25:26    |     Syed    |   OK   |
...
```

Table **users** (all of the columns has value, but removed for GDPR reasons):

```
| ID | displayname | fullname | email |
|  1 |     Angel   |          |       | 
|  2 |     Nico    |          |       | 
|  3 |    Raquie   |          |       | 
|  4 |    Cabil    |          |       | 
|  5 |    Syed     |          |       |
...
```

I have a PHP script that looks like this:

```
<?php      
   $query = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE status='OK' ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s') DESC LIMIT 5";
       if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
              $num_rows = 0;
              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  $num_rows++;

                  echo '<div class="my-box">';
                  echo "{$row['id']}";
                  echo "{$row['date']}";
                  echo "{$row['dbirth']}";
                  echo "{$row['email']}";
                  echo "{$row['displayname']}";
                  echo '</div>';
              }
              $result->free();
          }
      ?>
```

Now it currently displays each displayname for each sale in `echo "{$row['displayname']}";`, but insted of the displayname, I want to show the fullname for the user that has the current display name. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for a join:

```
select s.*, u.fullname
from sales s
inner join users u on u.displayname = u.displayname
```

Comment: I pasted the `query` wrong, can you take a look again? Or should I be using the same approach?

Comment: @Kama: that's still the same thing. You need a `join` to bring the corresponding row from `users`.

Comment: Ok, so do I replace my `query = "` and add your code into the `query = "` insted? Can you show me an example of usage please?